# How to fire onSelect of a extjs 3.4 combo when loading a Store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Here is my code -

```
Store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
url: 'url',
totalProperty: 'count',
id: 'Code',
root: 'rows',
autoLoad: true,
triggerAction: 'all',
fields: ['title', 'description'],
listeners: {
    load: {
        fn: function (store) {
            Ext.getCmp('Combo').setValue(store.getAt('1').get('title'));
            Ext.getCmp('Combo').fireEvent('select');
        }
    }
}
}
);

xtype: 'combo',
id: 'Combo',
store: Store,
fieldLabel: 'title',
displayField: 'title',
valueField: 'title',
typeAhead: false,
editable: false,
allowBlank: false,
mode: 'local',
emptyText: 'Select...',
forceSelection: true,
triggerAction: 'all',
name: 'DefaultCombo',
selectOnFocus: true,
width: 150
, onSelect: function () {
alert('message');
}
```

Combobox value is being set here, but `onSelect` is not firing here. 
**I am using 3.4 version**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested out this in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/40f). The `onSelect` function appears to only fire when a selection is made.  However, if you add a listener for the `select` event instead that fire's in either case.

```
listeners: {
            select:function(){
                console.log('Select Event Fired!')
            }
        },
```

Comment: Hi, @Weeksdev I tried the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/40f) you posted but it doesn't work on Google chrome. Does it work for you on Google Chrome?

Comment: Thanks!  Just figured it's only happens on the chrome from one of the machines.

Comment: No errors in the console. It's repeatable only on one desktop.

Comment: @leoh Is there anything in the network tab that is getting dropped or not coming back 200 ok?  Does a fresh install of chrome on that machine fix the issue?